# BJTs dangerously getting hotter as drawn current accumulating

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, bjt, biasing, class-ab

I already ask a few  questions on this project (so i won't explain everything again as it would be too long). I basically have a high power opamp (OPA462) to which i feed a signal (but i offset it with a voltage divider before in order to avoid negative output voltage values). Then i boost the output current with 2 BJTs (it's looks a lot like an AB amplifier):

Some of you told me to not test this circuit in real life, but i did. And it worked really good. I just had one unpredicted problem: my power supply is showing the current drawn by the circuit accumulating as soon as i am ***NOT*** sending any signal (so basically the circuit is just powered ON but no AC signal is being sent). But as soon as i send a signal, that *current rising with time phenomenon* disappears, but restarts immediatly as soon as the signal is OFF. When the current is rising, the transistors gets hot proportionally (i tested it several times and they seem to get a bit hot at around 300mA).

So my take on this is that that "current leak" is happening in the region where there is the BJTs and the power supply, so if you look at my circuit below , the problem should be happening from Vcc_U1 passing through BJT Q2 then BJT Q1 and finally to V3. And i guess than the voltage output of the opamp is the culprit.

You can see the current passing through the emitter of the BJTs shutting ON and OFF alternatively when there is a signal (so i guess in that case the V_be of the BJTs is well defined, meaning it's completly CLOSED or OPEN) BUT when no signal is sent, the output voltage of the opamp is just the constant offset value (60 volts).

I feel like this is where i should try to find the solution as this voltage may be giving a V_be not small enough to shut the 2 BJTS completly OFF. Is there a way to stop that current leak by reducing these V_be when the signal is OFF? But also when ON because there is room for improvement regarding Q2's performances (current is not complety 0mA as opposed to Q1)

```
                  ///////////////////////////  WHEN THE SIGNAL IS ON /////////////////////
```

[image: SIGNAL ON]

And here is what the BJTs's V_be looks like when the signal is ON :

[image]

```
                  //////////////////////////   WHEN THE SIGNAL IS OFF   //////////////////
```

[image: SIGNAL OFF]

And here is what the BJTs's V_be looks like when the signal is OFF :

[image]

Btw, i'm a noob in electronics so please keep the explanation as simple as possbile.
Thanks in advance for your precious help !

Comment: You should reference other posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my power supply is showing the current drawn by the circuit accumulating as soon as i am NOT sending any signal

That's what we EEs call the **quiescent current** or **biasing current**.

> You can see the current passing through the emitter of the BJTs shutting ON and OFF alternatively

That means you have a "class AB output stage". [Read more here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/class-ab-amplifier.html).

Class A means the transistors always stay on.

Class B means the transisors "take turns" one is on, the other is of and vise versa.

You have a class AB stage, both transistors are on when the signal is small (or when there is no signal) only when the signal is somewhat large, the circuit operates in class B.

I suggest that you lower that biasing current so that the ciruit will operate closer to class B. Note that the closer you get to class B, the more signal distortion you might get at certain signal levels. This does not have to be an issue! It depends on how much signal distortion you can tolerate.

*How do I lower that biasing current?*

That current is mostly determined by the base-emitter voltages of the transistors. The base-emitters of Q1 and Q2 are in series and here their voltage is set by D1 and D2.

If you would lower the voltage across D1 and D2 that would lower the biasing current. Unfortunately, this is not so easy.

A much easier and safer option is to "burn" some of that voltage across some small resistors. I would add a small value resistor (start with 0.1 ohm) in series with the emitters of Q1 and Q2 and simulate to see what happens.

That part of your circuit would then look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4bVMJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried your last suggestion on LTspice and it reduces the quiescent current to 7 mA when using 2x 10 ohms resistors at the common emitter location. I see that as soon as i try to increase their value  in the hope to get less than 7mA, a bit of distortion can be seen. I still don't know if it is a problem (i really have to get low distortion though..) but the good news is that it brings the quiescent current at 4mA (with 25ohms resistor).

Comment: The big question that i have right now is the following one : I plan to test this solution by monday, is it still going to accumulate and rise with time ? (if yes, i guess at a slower rate..? ) Also, WHY does it accumulate ?

Comment: Accumulate? Maybe you mean that the current **increases** over time? That is probably caused by the transistors **warming up**, for a certain \$V_{BE}\$ (Base Emitter voltage) a certain \$I_C\$ (Collector current) will flow. When the temperature of the transistor increases (it warms up), that \$I_C\$ will also increase, even though \$V_{BE}\$ stays constant. It is a property of BJTs. When you decrease the biasing current, this effect will still exist but it will be **much less** as the transistors should not get as hot as before. ...

Comment: ... So the current will still increase but it should settle (become fairly constant) after a while. In some amplifiers the diodes D1 and D2 will be **thermally coupled** to Q1 and Q2. This can be done by simply mounting them all to the same heatsink. Then when the transistors get hotter, so do the diodes. Diodes will **decrease** their forward voltage when temperature rises so that will also stabilize the biasing current. I don't think this is needed in your situation as you want fairly low currents, then the resistors I suggested are an easier option.

Comment: Thanks ! You perfectly answered my question ! Very very interesting informations ! I will try it then and hope it will work as you said ! I am also quite impressed by your last answer, i can't understand how people came up with that idea of thermally coupling two different components in such a way to get what they were searching for (stabilization of the quiescent current).

Comment: *i can't understand how people came up with that idea of thermally coupling two different components* It's not that hard. Diodes and transistors both use PN-junctions making them behave in similar ways. So to prevent the biasing current through the transistors from increasing over temperature, you would want the biasing voltage (the voltage between the base of Q1 and base of Q2 to change such that this doesn't happen. So the voltage needs to **decrease** when the temperature **increases**. Hmm, that's exactly what a diode does :-) so if you make diode and BJT same temperature...

Comment: You may also wish to explore the 'VBE Multiplier' in place of the diodes, lets you dial in whatever your desired bias current is. Lowest crossover distortion is typically at Vt/Re (so 26mA with a 1 ohm emitter resistor, but this can get annoyingly large with small resistances).

Comment: Thanks guys for all these informations ! I just tested the solution with 2x 50ohms resistors and it works ! :DDD